# Limit the content length of search result in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can i limit the content length or character limit in search result of wordpress?

I want something like what the `the_excerpt()` does.

I used `get_template_part('loop', 'search')` in my page. Then what I have to change in `search.php` or `loop.php`.

Is there any options to do this?

Comment: So after ca. one year after, how have you solved that?

Answer (score 1):

Lots. [`substr`](http://us.php.net/substr) comes to mind. A more sophisticated solution might be to create a function (in functions.php of your theme) `shorten($content)` that takes the text to be shortened and:

1. Strips the HTML tags
2. Returns a string of the first n words

Look at the `wp_trim_excerpt()` function in wp-includes/formatting.php in your wordpress install for an example.

Comment: How can i apply this to only search resultt?

Comment: By only using it in the search result template.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the_excerpt() with a filter as explained in the codex?

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters

Comment: How can i apply this to only search resultt?